# How to make localization work with laravelcollective/html

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I want to translate label. There is label:

```
{{ Form::label('name', 'name') }}
```

So, I need something like:

```
{{ Form::label('name', @lang('messages.name')) }}
```

I have an option, write it with `<label>` tag, but is there any option to achieve translation with laravelcollective/html

Comment: Does that not work? Do you get errors? Would `{{ Form::label('name', __('messages.name')) }}` do it?

Comment: @brombeer ```__``` works, also ```trans``` helper works https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-trans

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ Form::label('name', trans('messages.name')) }}
```

works great! Hope it helps someone